# Fixed points on spherical buildings

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, isometries, buildings

A crucial aspect of the Bruhat–Tits theory of affine buildings is the [Bruhat–Tits fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat%E2%80%93Tits_fixed_point_theorem), which, in one of many formulations, states that, if $\Gamma$ is a group of isometries of an affine building and $S$ is a closed, bounded, convex, $\Gamma$-stable subset of the affine building, then $\Gamma$ admits a fixed point on $S$.

Is there any similar result for spherical buildings (specifically of spherical buildings attached to semisimple groups, in case there are more results for them than for general spherical buildings)?  I am particularly interested in results of the form:  if $\Gamma$ is a group of isometries of a spherical building and $S$ is a […] $\Gamma$-stable subset of the spherical building, then $\Gamma$ admits a fixed point on $S$.  For example, does this hold if we require $S$ to be closed and convex?  (Probably not.)  Does it hold if we require $S$ also to be contractible, or perhaps just never to contain two opposite simplices?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, thank you!  It seems to me that your comment is an answer, so I hope you will make it as such so that I can accept it.

Comment: I guess you ask that $\Gamma$ stabilizes $S$ ?

Comment: @PaulBroussous, thanks!  You are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421218/fixed-points-on-spherical-buildings#comment1084149_421218), and I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since spherical buildings are CAT(1), we get a fixed point if $$\mathop{\rm rad}S<\tfrac \pi 2.$$

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know a good reference for $\operatorname{CAT}(\kappa)$-spaces for someone who is not a geometer?  I know a little bit about $\operatorname{CAT}(0)$-spaces because of my work with affine buildings, but I have mostly just encountered them under the general rubric of "spaces of non-positive curvature", not as part of a general family.

Comment: @LSpice  a reference-book for CAT⁡(κ)-spaces: https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08539 (sorry for the self-advertisement).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421218/fixed-points-on-spherical-buildings/421410#comment1083086_421410), it's hardly an ad--I asked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Tits centre conjecture, on which I am hardly an expert and so do not propose to offer a literature survey but which was proven for thick spherical buildings (in particular for spherical buildings of semisimple groups) in [Ramos-Cuevas - The center conjecture for thick spherical buildings](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10711-012-9799-9), says that, if $S$ is a convex subcomplex of a spherical building $B$, and $S$ is not itself a spherical building, then the stabiliser in $\operatorname{Aut}(B)$ of $S$ admits a fixed point on $S$.  This seems to answer my question:  it holds when $S$ is contractible.