# Symmetries of contractable subsets of $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, symmetry

Let $K\subset\Bbb R^n$ be a non-empty compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$. A symmetry of $K$ is an isometry of $\Bbb R^n$ that fixes $K$ set-wise. Since $K$ is compact, there is always a point $x\in\Bbb R^n$ fixed by all symmetries.

> **Question:** Can the following three things be true at the same time:
>
> 1. $K$ is contractible.
> 2. $x$ is the only point fixed by all symmetries of $K$.
> 3. $x\not\in K$.

The following image shows that such a $K$ exists if we ignore one of the properties:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure it's obvious to anyone who might be in a position to answer this question, but why does the compactness of $K$ imply that $G = \operatorname{Isom}(\mathbb R^n, K)$ has a fixed point on $\mathbb R^n$?  I could imagine buying it if we had some sort of appropriate compactness for $G$; do we?

Comment: @LSpice I considered this folklore, but I have no quick argument at hand. My vague intuition is that if $g\in G$ has not fixed point then it sends $x\mapsto Ax + b$ with $A$ fixing the orthogonal complement of $b$. So no orbit of $G$ can be compact.

Comment: @LSpice a result of Jung (1905) is that every nonempty bounded subset of a Hilbert space is contained in a unique ball of minimal radius. In particular the center of this ball is fixed by the isometry group.

Comment: [That](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1085386) seems only to argue that every $g$ has a fixed point, not that all of $G$ does; but @YCor's [citation](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1085388) does the job. I guess the latter is a special case of the [Bruhat–Tits fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat%E2%80%93Tits_fixed_point_theorem), which I should have thought of since I recently [asked a question about it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421218).  Thanks!

Comment: I'm probably making a stupid mistake, but isn't half sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ such an example?

Comment: @NickS The symmetries of the half-sphere fix an axis.

Comment: @M.Winter As I was saying, stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted a refined/generalized question [Does a compact contractible metric space have a point that is fixed by all isometries?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/422464/108884) and received an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/422474/108884) that contained all essential ingredients to provide an affirmative answer to this question. The related question [Homeomorphic to the disk implies existence of fixed point common to all isometries?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499826/415941) has an answer with further very interesting details.

There are two ingredients:

1. there exists a group $G$ that acts without fixed points on the $n$-dimensional ball (for an appropriate $n>5$).
2. the ball can be smoothly embedded into some Euclidean space $\Bbb R^m$ so that the action of $G$ is now by linear transformations and only fixes the origin (Mostow's embedding theorem).

If we choose $K$ to be this embedded ball and $x$ to be the origin, then this configuration satisfies all the conditions from my question.

References to the claims 1 and 2 can be found in the linked answers, except for the assertion that the linear transformations only fix the origin, which I found in the original paper ["Equivariant Embeddings in Euclidean Space" by Mostow](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970055).

Comment: So under this embedding, the disc does not contain the origin?

Comment: @Bma Yes, because otherwise the action of $G$ on the disc would have a fixed point.

Comment: You refer to "the linked answers", but you link only one.  Did you mean to link others?

Comment: @LSpice I mean the answers below the linked questions, but mostly the first linked question.

Comment: What would $m$ be for $n=6$? Any chance some other solution could exist in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Yaakov I don't know how $m$ depends on $n$. I haven't checked how explicit Mostow's theorem is about this. A comment below the linked answer states that you cannot have examples for $n\le 4$ as every group acting on a ball in dimension up to four has a fixed point. The case $n=5$ is open. And of course $m\ge n$.

Answer (score -2):

As I see, the answer is “no”. If you have the single fixed point $X$ not from your set, then the symmetry of your compact is a reflection to the line $l$ which contains $X$.

It is easy to see that you cannot have another reflection line. Because if you have it, then their composition — rotation, is also a symmetry of your compact. But if you have a rotation, then $X$ is a centre of the corresponding circle and it's easy to the сontradiction to contractability.
And because of contractibility defined line l must intersect K. And that would be another fixed point which is in K.

Comment: I don't understand your claim "then the symmetry...". For instance, if the group of symmetries consists of $\{\mathrm{id},-\mathrm{id}\}$ (so $x=0$), the assumption is $K=-K$, $0\notin K$. In particular a subquestion is whether there exists a nonempty contractible compact subset $K$ of $\mathbf{R}^n$ such that $0\notin K$ and $K=-K$.